# OS X software for panning the desktop

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec

[image]

Just like the picture. My display is very small, but I need a large area for Programming,
so I just think that if there is a software like the picture.
when I drag the red rectangle, the display part will be scrolled.

for Mac OS X.

I think 13 inch is not large and convenient enough for me to develop iPhone Program.
because I have to show and hide the Windows, I think it's a trouble.

Comment: Are you looking to have the system render more pixels than are supported by the display, and then zoom and pan around inside of that? You may be out of luck, though @edc1591's answer may help. Also getting to learn OS X's window management keyboard shortcuts and strategies may help you get the most out of a small display. Command-tab and command-` are your friends.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any software that does what you're asking, but my solution has always been to just use Spaces. With Xcode 4 it's not as much of a problem because everything is in one window, but back in the Xcode 3 days I would have Xcode in one space and Interface Builder in another.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a Zoom function you can find it under System Preferences: Universal Access

Answer (score 0):

Just hold control and scroll, it zooms in and out. You can change the behaviour of how it pans in the control panel.